# How to drop a column in a Pandas DataFrame which contains the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with some columns that have the same value in every row.

So something like:-

```
Col1    Col2     Col3 ....  ColX  ColY    ColZ
323     False    324          4    abc    Sync 
232     False    342          4    def    Sync
364     False    2343         4    ghi    Sync
```

So I would like to drop Col2, ColX and ColZ from the above DataFrame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare the DataFrame against a particular row (I chose the first one with `df.iloc[0]`) and use `loc` to select the columns that satisfy the condition you specified:

```
df.loc[:, ~(df == df.iloc[0]).all()]
Out: 
   Col1  Col3 ColY
0   323   324  abc
1   232   342  def
2   364  2343  ghi
```

---

Timings:

[@root's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493292/how-to-drop-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-which-contains-the-same-value/40493359#comment68231562_40493695), `nunique`, is quite faster than comparing the Series against a single value. Unless you have a huge number of columns (thousands, for example) iterating over columns as [@MMF suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493695/2285236) looks like a more efficient approach.

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.loc[:, ~(df == df.iloc[0]).all()]
1 loop, best of 3: 377 ms per loop

%timeit df[[col for col in df if not df[col].nunique()==1]]
10 loops, best of 3: 35.6 ms per loop


df = pd.concat([df]*10, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.loc[:, ~(df == df.iloc[0]).all()]
1 loop, best of 3: 3.71 s per loop

%timeit df[[col for col in df if not df[col].nunique()==1]]
1 loop, best of 3: 353 ms per loop


df = pd.concat([df]*3, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.loc[:, ~(df == df.iloc[0]).all()]
1 loop, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop

%timeit df[[col for col in df if not df[col].nunique()==1]]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Solved.

Comment: can you add a timing comparison for a bigger DF? My wild guess - your solution will be faster...

Comment: @MaxU: From my timings the other solution is faster.

Comment: @MaxU I've added timings.

Comment: @root What was the number of columns for the one you tried? I guess iterating over columns slowing down the other solution when there are many columns. I've actually increased the number of columns so that I could have a big df with columns that have the same values but it may not be representative of course.

Comment: @ayhan: I just used `df = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)` where `df` contains the original data posted in the question, so more rows but less columns.

Comment: @root, ayhan, thank you. I had a small typo in my script... Now I could reproduce root's results. So basically as ayhan has mentioned in his answer it'll depend on the shape's DF and will be faster if # of columns is pretty high

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this checking the length of the set generated by the values of each column :

```
df = df[[col for col in df if not len(set(df[col]))==1]]
```

Comment: FYI, `df[col].nunique()==1`  is faster than `len(set(df[col]))==1`.

Comment: if some columns have same values throughout, and if its a big dataframe, than maybe just comparing the first two or three sequential columns values will be enough to eliminate the whole column.Why do we need to check for the entire column?

Comment: @root Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) and [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html), to obtain the column names with more than one unique value:

```
In [6]: df[df.columns[df.nunique() > 1]]
Out[6]: 
   Col1  Col3 ColY
0   323   324  abc
1   232   342  def
2   364  2343  ghi
```